# Java - How to compress using deflater with dynamic byte size

Tags: java, compression, deflate, deflatestream

How to compress byte array using deflater?
I tried with deflate inflate example from Oracle page. It worked fine.

My doubt is how to make byte[] size dynamic.?
And how to calculate before and after compression of byte[]?

Answer (score 0):

The API is a bit confusing. 
Take a look at [finished()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#finished--) which tells you *after* attempting to compress into a too-small buffer that it was too small.

Your only chance to go on is either

- incrementally increasing the buffer if `finished()==false` and/or
- starting with a sufficient big buffer (that might be too small also).

One alternative could be using [DeflaterOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html) writing into a [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html), but that's much more high-level than the approach you were asking for.